# How to disable internal pytest warnings?

Tags: python, warnings, pytest

I want to disable all pytest internal warnings like `PytestCacheWarning` in `pytest.ini` but currently have no luck with it. The following ini file doesn't work as I expect:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings:
    ignore::pytest.PytestCacheWarning
```

What is the right way to do it? Note: I don't want to disable all warnings, only those defined inside pytest implementation.

---

Minimal reproducible example:

1) Create the following structure:

```
some_dir/
    .pytest_cache/
    test_something.py
    pytest.ini
```

2) Put this into `test_something.py` file:

```
def test_something():
    assert False
```

3) Put this into `pytest.ini` file:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings:
    ignore::pytest.PytestCacheWarning
```

4) do `chmod 444 .pytest_cache` to procude `PytestCacheWarning: could not create cache path` warning

5) run `pytest`:

```
========================== test session starts ===========================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/sanyash/repos/reproduce_pytest_bug, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: celery-4.4.0, aiohttp-0.3.0
collected 1 item                                                         

test_something.py F                                                [100%]

================================ FAILURES ================================
_____________________________ test_something _____________________________

    def test_something():
>       assert False
E       assert False

test_something.py:2: AssertionError
============================ warnings summary ============================
/home/sanyash/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:137
  /home/sanyash/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:137: PytestCacheWarning: could not create cache path /home/sanyash/repos/reproduce_pytest_bug/.pytest_cache/v/cache/stepwise
    self.warn("could not create cache path {path}", path=path)

/home/sanyash/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:137
  /home/sanyash/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:137: PytestCacheWarning: could not create cache path /home/sanyash/repos/reproduce_pytest_bug/.pytest_cache/v/cache/nodeids
    self.warn("could not create cache path {path}", path=path)

/home/sanyash/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:137
  /home/sanyash/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/cacheprovider.py:137: PytestCacheWarning: could not create cache path /home/sanyash/repos/reproduce_pytest_bug/.pytest_cache/v/cache/lastfailed
    self.warn("could not create cache path {path}", path=path)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
===================== 1 failed, 3 warnings in 0.03s ======================
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use the import path to ignore it:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::pytest.PytestCacheWarning
```

so for all pytest warnings you would use the common base class:

```
[pytest]
filterwarnings =
    ignore::pytest.PytestWarning
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still doesn't work. I slightly changed my question to include reproducible example and switched from `PytestAssertRewriteWarning` to `PytestCacheWarning`.

Comment: Thanks, having read through [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html#internal-pytest-warnings) it appears my answer is what should work so it may be an issue with pytest. I suggest filing an issue at the pytest github.

Comment: in case you are interested: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/6681